# 3d multilateration with unknown, but proportional, distances

Tags: indoor-positioning-system, trilateration

I am trying to position a digital unit using a number of receivers by recording the signal strength at each receiver.

However, since not all digital units will emit with the same signal strength I cannot use the traditional approaches to multilateration (that I've heard of at least).

Could someone help me do this?

I've tried by considering the signal strengths [RSSI] as proportional to one another and subsequently tried to project them onto a coordinate system [m] - but just can't seem to get it right.

***EDIT:***

Essentially I want to reformulate this problem:

**FIND** coordinates of P

**Given:**

- coordinates of receivers/nodes A,B,C in a 2D-plane :
  {x_A,y_A,...,y_C} [unit: m]
- signal strength received at the nodes from unknown point P:
  {|RSSI_AP|,...,|RSSI_CP|}

Into this problem (that is easily solved using a trilateration algorithm):

**FIND** coordinates of P

**GIVEN:**

- coordinates of receivers/nodes A,B,C in a 2D-plane :
  {x_A,y_A,...,y_C} [unit: m]
- distance to point P from the receivers: {d_AP,d_BP,d_CP}

Comment: This is StackOverflow and people ask about coding problems. Your question doesn't seem to be related to any programming problem. I encourage you to post your question [here] (http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) instead

Comment: Thank you very much for the swift response Amir!

Ah, okay, I edited the question so that it would be more clear that it should be more of a mathematical/algorithmical problem. Do you still think it does not belong. 

(The reason I am asking is because I want to be indifferent to hardware specifics)